# Style SVG when parent has certain class

Tags: css, svg

Other than embedding an SVG inline, how can I apply a different fill when its parent has the class `layout-active`?

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="layout-toggle layout-active">
    <img src="build/img/calendar-view-01.svg" />
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="layout-toggle">
    <img src="build/img/calendar-view-02.svg" />
  </div>
</a>
```

I've tried adding some CSs to the .svg file, but `.layout-active` is out of its scope.

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/

Comment: you can't (without making it inline)

Comment: That's all I needed to know. Thanks